# can't copy deep folder structure with gulp

Tags: node.js, stream, gulp

I"m getting the strangest behavior.

I have a gulp file it has three tasks. clean, copy a bunch of stuff to a folder, copy entire folder to other destination.

It seems to copy MOST of the entire folder, but leaves certain folders empty.  There is no rhyme or reason, they are all folders that container javascript files and folders.  Makes no sense.

Here's what I got.

```
gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
    del([config.get("deploy.output.deploy"), config.get("deploy.buildDirectory")],{force:true}, cb);
});

gulp.task("copy-source",["clean"], function () {
    gulp.src("src/**")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.get("deploy.output.app")+"/src"));
    gulp.src(["package.json", "server.js", "bootstrap.js"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.get("deploy.output.app")));
    gulp.src("config/**")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.get("deploy.output.app")+"/config"));
    return gulp.src("deploy/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.get("deploy.output.deploy")));
});

gulp.task("copy-to-buildDir",["copy-source"], function () {
    return gulp.src(config.get("deploy.output.deploy")+"/**")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.get("deploy.buildDirectory")));
});

gulp.task("deploy",[ "copy-to-buildDir"]);
```

src folder structure looks like this, more or less obviously psudo structure

```
output
└── app
    ├── config
    │   └── file7.js
    ├── src
    │   ├── modules
    │   │   ├── ges
    │   │   │   ├── file1.js
    │   │   │   └── file2.js
    │   │   └── file3.js
    │   ├── file4.js
    │   └── controllers
    │       └── file5.js
    └── file6.js
```

dest folder structure looks like this

```
output
└── app
    ├── src
    │   ├── modules
    │   │   └── EMPTY
    │   └── controllers
    │       └── file5.js
    └── file6.js
```

so modules and controllers are sisters, and one has the files one does not.  makes no sense.

if you have any ideas I'd greatly appreciate it.

also the building up of the src (the first task) works every time.  Also 
I've tried just about every concievable permutation of the dependencies e.g. ["clean"]

Comment: you have multiple gulp.src in same task and only last one doing the return.. so basically it might finish even before other gulp.src have finished copying... try combining the source and having single gulp.src

Comment: Interesting. Sounds kind of o obvious when you spell it out.  Thanks, ill try later today.

Comment: @entre this seems to do the trick.  Can you make an actual answer with that info for posterity and so I can select it as correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below task definition is not correct

```
gulp.task("copy-source",["clean"], function () {
    gulp.src("src/**")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.get("deploy.output.app")+"/src"));
    gulp.src(["package.json", "server.js", "bootstrap.js"])
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.get("deploy.output.app")));
    gulp.src("config/**")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.get("deploy.output.app")+"/config"));
    return gulp.src("deploy/*")
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.get("deploy.output.deploy")));
});
```

you are doing 4 copies but checking the end of only final copy stream.

Either separate them into 4 tasks or combine the src and create single task to solve the issue